# Reading from javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, args

[image: JAVASCRIPT ARGS]

I want to access the "Value", how do i do that?

Comment: Next time, **tell us** what you tried.  This comes across as a very dumb question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply

```
var value = args.Value;
```

An equivalent way to do it (but which works also if you have `"Value"` in a variable) is

```
var value = args["Value"];
```